# how to read excel column with dates before and after year 1900

Tags: r, tidyverse, readxl

I am trying to import an xlsx spreadsheet containing birthdays from the year 1899 and earlier.

I use `read_excel()` from the **readxl** package and get warning messages such as below:

> In read_fun(path = path, sheet_i = sheet, limits = limits, shim =
>   shim,  :   Expecting date in B278 / R278C2: got '08/09/1897'

on inspection there are NAs where there should be dates.

Any help on how to import a mix of dates spanning 1900 would be appreciated.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm

Comment: can you please show your data

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LF9crBV9o-lv0UgSA_hVl7IkCIYvZieRZAJSaEvflUU